# Recorded video Frame using AVCaptureSession

Tags: iphone, ios, avcapturesession, video-recording

In my application i am using  `AVCaptureSession` to record `video`.

When recording done,I m getting video is of size **`360 X 480`**.

I have set recording layer size is **`320 X 568`**.

I am missing something, I tried but not getting where.

Can anyone guide me where should i change to get recording `video` with size of `320 X 568`

Here is my code,

Initialization

```
AVCaptureDevice* device = nil;
AVCaptureDeviceInput *captureInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:nil];
AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *captureOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
captureOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = YES; 



dispatch_queue_t queue;
queue = dispatch_queue_create("cameraQueue", NULL);
[captureOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];
dispatch_release(queue);
```

// Set the video output to store frame in BGRA

```
NSString* key = (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey; 
NSNumber* value = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]; 
NSDictionary* videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:value forKey:key]; 
[captureOutput setVideoSettings:videoSettings];
```

//And we create a capture session

```
self.captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
self.captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;

if([self.captureSession respondsToSelector:@selector(addInput:)])
        [self.captureSession addInput:captureInput];
    if([self.captureSession respondsToSelector:@selector(addOutput:)])
        [self.captureSession addOutput:captureOutput];

/*We add the Custom Layer (We need to change the orientation of the layer so that the video is displayed correctly)*/
self.customLayer = [CALayer layer];
self.customLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;

self.customLayer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(CATransform3DIdentity, M_PI/2.0f, 0, 0, 1);
    self.customLayer.transform = CATransform3DScale(self.customLayer.transform,.7,.7,1);
    self.customLayer.transform = CATransform3DTranslate(self.customLayer.transform,-23,0,0);

self.customLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspectFill;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:self.customLayer];
[self.captureSession startRunning];
```

//Initialization Over

Comment: Use `VideoSettings` Property.

Comment: make sure are you not forget to add iphone5 Default-568h@2x.png

Comment: @Nitin, Yes i have addded Default-568h@2x.png

Comment: ok then i hope you are checking properly that its device is iphone5 or not right..? if yes then you also set Layer size as par device so can you please share this code with your question then you we can understand your stuff

Comment: Yes, checking properly. and in 3.5" screen also its giving same size 360 X 480. ANd i have checked with changing layer size but no change.Adding code in question.

Comment: @Nitin, I have just added code, Please guide me if you find any mistake.

Answer (score 1):

can you please try with check before this line `self.customLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;` of code its iphone5 or not. if yes then set its frame manually like

you can check like:-

`#define isiPhone5  ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)?TRUE:FALSE`

```
//We add the Custom Layer (We need to change the orientation of the layer so that the video is displayed correctly)*/

self.customLayer = [CALayer layer];


if(isIphone5)
{
self.customLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);
}
else
{
self.customLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

}
```

hope this help's you my Frnd

Comment: Thanks for the reply Yes, I already did this. But not get any change.

Answer (score 1):

AvCaptureSessionMedium will not allow you for 320 * 568 image resolution. There is no property set for this resolution in AVCaptureSession.

AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium is used camera resolution of 360.000000 and 480.000000.
It's a default resolution for AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium, so it'll not work for iPhone-5 display.

If you want to get higher resolution image on iPhone-5, you should use AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh. but it'll provide you image resolution of 1980 * 1080. so it'll work fine but will increase size bytes of images.

Also you can check by this:

```
 AVCaptureSession *newCaptureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];    

     if (IS_IPHONE5) 
    {          
               newCaptureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh; 
    }
    else
            {
           newCaptureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if ([self.captureSession canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset320*568]) 
    {
        [self.captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset320*568];
    }
```

try this one.

Comment: Where is this option ?AVCaptureSessionPreset320*568. Its giving error.